# Styles in standard LaTeX distribution

Tags: distributions

A conference I'm submitting to wants any styles (and packages I assume) that are not in the 'standard latex distribution' to be included with the .tex source.

What are the standard styles and packages?

Comment: I would image they mean any packages you've written yourself to accompany your paper as opposed to packages available on [CTAN](http://ctan.org/).

Comment: @NicolaTalbot well what they probably mean is "not in the TeX distribution that they have installed in production" which is probably a debian texlive circa 2001....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle in 2001, I'd say tetex.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina i wrote tetex originally but was uncertain of my recollection of history and running out of edit time so changed it to texlive:-)